# Sending notification to a particular device

Tags: javascript, firebase, polymer, firebase-cloud-messaging, polymerfire

Displaying a notification is easy

```
function spawnNotification(theBody,theIcon,theTitle) {
  var options = {
    body: theBody,
    icon: theIcon
  }
  var n = new Notification(theTitle,options);
}
```

How do I send it to a particular device(token received via firebase-messaging). Is there a `to` parameter and if there is, where do I place it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [`to`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#downstream-http-messages-json) parameter. You place it in your message payload.

Additional related docs:

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message